# Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating <SFAuthenticationViewController>

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0

Getting quite a weird bug, trying to use some very simple code.

```
import SafariService

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    ///All my stuff

    @IBAction func connectToReddit(){
        let authURL = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=myID&response_type=code&state=myState&redirect_uri=myRedirectURI&duration=permanent&scope=myscopes")

        let scheme = "redditwatch://"
        let authSession = SFAuthenticationSession(url: authURL!, callbackURLScheme: scheme, completionHandler: { (url, error) in
            print(url?.absoluteString)
            print(error?.localizedDescription)

        })

        authSession.start()

    }
}
```

It is to my understanding that `authSession.start()` presents the user with a `UIAlertController`, which with my code, it *does* do, but the controller disappears moments after, with the error

```
[Warning] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x7fc1c201f600>)
```

You'd think creating this auth flow would be simpler, but apparently not.

Appreciate any input, thanks

Comment: Without knowing anything much about oauth, I'd guess it's because `authSession` only has local scope within your function.  What happens if you declare it as an instance variable of your controller?

Comment: The scope consideration is directly referenced here: https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/ios-11-privacy-and-single-sign-on-6291687a2ccc under the heading "Closer Look"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the SFAuthenticationSession at the top-level.
This should correct the issue:

```
import SafariService

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    var authSession: SFAuthenticationSession?

    ///All my stuff
    @IBAction func connectToReddit(){
        let authURL = URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=myID&response_type=code&state=myState&redirect_uri=myRedirectURI&duration=permanent&scope=myscopes")

        let scheme = "redditwatch://"
        authSession = SFAuthenticationSession(url: authURL!, callbackURLScheme: scheme, completionHandler: { (url, error) in
            print(url?.absoluteString)
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        })

        authSession?.start()
    }
}
```

Credit for this fix to this Medium post: https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/ios-11-privacy-and-single-sign-on-6291687a2ccc
I could not find a reference to the scope issue in the official documentation.

Edit: The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfauthenticationsession) now states "Ensure that there is a strong reference to the SFAuthenticationSession instance when the session is in progress." This seems to indicate the need to move the session up in scope. This is due to the behavior that occurs when the SFAuthenticationSession initializer displays the consent dialog.

Edit2: SFAuthenticationSession was deprecated in iOS 12 and replaced with ASWebAuthenticationSession. However, ASWebAuthenticationSession has the same scope requirement. [This blog](https://ajkueterman.com/apple/wwdc/sfauthenticationsession-and-aswebauthenticationsession/) has a good description of how to convert.

Comment: Sorry for the super late accepting! I was away interstate without my laptop for 10 days